# Within SwiftUI, how to pin a component to the bottom of the screen?

Tags: swift, swiftui-list

Using SwiftUI (edited for brevity), I have a number of components that make up a screen:

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    var foo: Foo;

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Text 1")
            Text("Text 2")
            Text("Text 3")
            Text("Text 4")

            List {
                ForEach(self.foo.fooItems) { fooItem in
                   ...
                }
            }

            Text("Want to pin this to the bottom")
        }
    }
}
```

If I put the *Text("Want to pin this to the bottom")* above the List it will be displayed, however, if I put it below the list, it disappears.  Each of the Text components is fixed, so it was my belief that the *List* component would alter it's size as it is the only component that is flexible to alter its height but that does not seem to be so.

I constructed such designs on numerous occasions with Interface Builder but I have not seen any example where someone is pinning a component to the bottom of the screen using SwiftUI.  Thoughts on how to pin a component to the bottom of the screen using SwiftUI?

Comment: Do you want to make the text scroll with the List (as the last item of the list) or have it always stay at the bottom of the screen? If it's the latter, your code already does that (on Xcode 11). Or are you using Xcode 12?

Comment: I want it pinned to the bottom of the screen, not scrolling.  I am using Xcode 11.5.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
        ScrollView{
           VStack(alignment: .leading) {
               Text("Text 1")
               Text("Text 2")
               Text("Text 3")
               List {
                   ForEach(self.foo.fooItems) { fooItem in
                      ...
                   }
               }
               Spacer()
           }
        }
        Text("Want to pin this to the bottom")
    }
```

I think you can combine ZStack and Spacer.
If the content or list seems to be larger than the screen size, use a ScrollView.

Comment: The content would be larger than the screen, however, using a ScrollView and a List, I would have scroll within a scroll which was problematic within Interface Builder.